# Execute background system command and capture output in a array using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to ping a bunch of IPs using PHP/HTML.

```
<?php
$ip=array("192.10.1.1","192.10.1.2","192.10.1.3","192.10.1.4","192.10.1.5")

$list=count($ip);
$instruction = "";

for ($x=0; $x<$list; $x++)
{
   if ($x > 0)
   {
      $send2_bg =" & ";
   }
   else
   {
     $send2_bg = "";
   }

$instruction = $instruction.$send2_bg."ping -c 2 -w 1 ". $ip[$x]." | grep -i received | awk '{print $4}'" ;
}

echo $instruction;
$result =exec($instruction);
 ?>
```

Expected output array

```
    1 1 0 0 2
```

But I'm failing to get the output, The instruction is constructed perfectly but after exec(), the output is not as I expect.

Comment: You can not ping using HTML.

Comment: @hjpotter92 He is using exec in php which can ping.

Comment: I am calling PHP not just HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec()` just returns the last line of the output

`shell_exec()` returns all output

Comment: Yes it does. But you only get the last line of the output. You could get all of it by either using shell_exec() or by supplying an additional $output variable.

Comment: You're right, Joel, thanks. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have obtained the expected output using shell_exec()

Answer (score 2):

Try capturing the output like this:

```
exec($command, $host, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are echoing the instruction var see that link -  [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/function.exec)

Please reffer to the parameter output and echo that one instead the instruction var.